# Please respect image copyright

Tags: discussion, images

Please do your best to not infringe on others’ copyright, in particular watermarked photos from sites such as iStock or Shutterstock.

If you’re asking about how an image is made, you should be including a citation to where it came from.

If you’re answering a question, you should be trying to use either images or photos you own the rights to or one of the many free stock-image websites, such as:

- [Unsplash](http://www.unsplash.com)
- [Superfamous](http://superfamous.com)
- [Death to the Stock Photo](http://join.deathtothestockphoto.com/)

See also:

- [Where are some good places to find royalty free stock images?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/115)

And even those may ask that citation is provided.

As we are a community of designers that wouldn’t want our own work stolen, please show that same courtesy to others by not stealing theirs.

While [we do not need to play copyright police](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240736/255554), we also don’t have to allow blatant theft.

Answer (score -7):

This is an educational forum and as such it can be considered a fair use environment. Copyright only applies if you are attempting to profit from the work.

> [T]he fair use of a copyrighted work, including such use by reproduction in copies or phonorecords or by any other means specified by that section, for purposes such as criticism, comment, news reporting, teaching (including multiple copies for classroom use), scholarship, or research, is not an infringement of copyright.

http://www.dmlp.org/legal-guide/fair-use

Comment: This is incorrect. For example: Showing a Disney design to discuss the concept and history of Disney is fair use. Taking a Disney design to teach about Photoshop or alter is not.

Comment: What's your opinion regarding contents of the link?

Comment: Copyright is a matter of law. I quoted the law.

Comment: Your link says *"A common misconception is that any for-profit use of someone else's work is not fair use and that any not-for-profit use is fair. In actuality, some for-profit uses are fair and some not-for-profit uses are not"* which specifically contradicts what you said *"Copyright only applies if you are attempting to profit from the work."*

Comment: I understand wholeheartedly the issue, although this does not offer a solution. If someone needs help with a copyrighted image from a stock image website, how can they get help without sharing it? Maybe after help has been obtained the file can be removed and replaced by screenshots? Guidelines would help